# How to add Webpack to a project for strictly minification?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, webpack, minify

I am a dev on a web application that consists of Java Server Pages which act as the HTML, a Java backend, and Javascript front-end files. I have been tasked with looking into adding Webpack to the project, with the goal of only using it to minify Javascript files at first (eventually we will use more of Webpack's features of course). I have tried doing research via Google into Webpack minification, but I am having trouble finding anything detailing how to use it for **just** minification, instead of bundling the project files.

Does anyone know how to use Webpack for strictly Javscript minification?

Answer (score 3):

Webpack out of the box is anticipating on processing JS and will run minification on `production` builds by default.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/ (different build modes)

Assuming you are already past configuring a JS entry file to consume all your JS files:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry

AND configured a loader on how to handle each JS file imported in your entry file appropriately.
(Feels like you want `asset/resource`. Pay close attention to asset modules `type` and `generator` options)
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

The settings for minification on a production build are what is known as the `optimization.minimize` configuration of your webpack.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimize

With Webpack5, further options around the minification engine has been exposed and is known as `optimization.minimizer` configuration options:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimizer

Comment: Devin thank you for the in-depth response. I have a question though -- if I define an entry point, wouldn't that result in Webpack bundling my files? I am trying to use Webpack strictly for minification at first, without the bundling feature. Is that possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer to note a needed loader configuration for JS that defines Webpack5's Asset Module type. This allows you to better define how your entry file(s) imported JS will be bundled or output as individual files.

Comment: I don't quite understand -- I am very new to Webpack and have not configured anything yet. My main question is, is it possible to use Webpack strictly for minification of Javascript files? And if so, how would I configure webpack.config.js to achieve this? I understand that it seems like overkill to use Webpack for just minification and not bundling, but this is the assignment I was given.